# differentiating among multiple tokens in a grammar

Tags: antlr

I have a grammar that looks like this:

```
stmt
 : ( TYPE1 expr )? ( TYPE2 expr ( ',' expr )* )?
 ;
```

How can I tell whether a given `expr` appeared right after `TYPE1` or `TYPE2`? The `Context` objects for all `expr`s are grouped together into a single list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rule is a bit odd. It can match nothing, because everything is optional.

However, the child list of the stmt context contains the sub contexts as they were recognized. And the other contexts (`TYPE1` and `TYPE2`) have a value only if they have been matched (btw. these convenience accessors ultimately work with the child list too). So by testing `stmtContext.TYPE1()` you can determine if the first part matched. Similarly for the second part via `TYPE2`.